# Transform a python folder into a package: `ModuleNotFoundError`

Tags: python, python-module

Suppose that in a folder `my_package`, i have three files :

- `__init__.py`, blanck
- `file1.py`, containing a functon `function1`
- `file2.py`, containing the import statement : `from file1 import function1`

Then, from another directory, when I use `import my_package.file2 as file2`, I have a `ModuleNotFoundError` coming from the line of the statement `from file1 import function1`.

Obviously, i did something wrong somewhere. But where ? The MWE i gave is small, but i append to have a lot of python files in `my_package` folder, some of them importing each other. I'm trying to change this directory into a package that i can import from elsewhere, that's why i added the `__init__.py` blanck file, but it does not seem to work that way.

Comment: what is your directory structure? This matters, unfortunately!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose i found the solution myself : I added a setup.py file with propper content to the folder and then i ran `pip -m my_package`, allowing me to import it from everywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Check this tree structure.

```
my_package
  |
  '-----  __init__.py
  '----- file1.py
  '----- file2.py

Script   (somewhere in your system)
  |
  '--- test.py
```

when you import my_package (import my_package.file2 as file2) in the another directory say in test.py, it looks for the directory named my_package in its current path.. (i.e. inside Script folder )

as my_package is not present inside the Script folder you will get the error ModuleNotFoundError.

so in test.py write the code as shown below

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/MyFiles/my_package")  # absolute path of the my_package folder

import file2

# Now use file2 and work on it

# all other modules/files in my_package folder can also be  imported.
```